# Accessing structure fields from the structure itself in Common LISP

Tags: common-lisp

For my project, I specifically need a structure that has (among other things) 2 slots:

- one holds data (current-state, a structure)
- one holds a function (is-state-a-solution)

That function slot must evaluate the current-state and return a result based on it. However, I can't find how to do this properly. Here's a segment of my code.

```
(defstruct state moves-left)

(defstruct problem
    (current-state)
    (solution (function (lambda () (null (state-moves-left :current-state)))))
)
```

No errors on compiling, but they happen when I interpret this:

```
> (setq p0 (make-problem :current-state (make-state)))
> (funcall (problem-solution p0))

SYSTEM::%STRUCTURE-REF: :CURRENT-STATE is not a structure of type STATE
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? I usually just use common functions, but these structure and slots are hard requirements.

EDIT: thanks for the answers. After learning this was impossible, I reread the requirements more thoroughly and posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302129/3304536).

Comment: Looking back without touching Lisp for a couple of years, this question looks really confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning this was impossible, I reread the requirements more thoroughly and found out this function will actually receive an argument (a state). So, the code now works:

```lisp
(defstruct problem
    (current-state)
    (solution (function (lambda (state) (not (null (state-moves-left state))))))
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could have a separate *create* function:

```
(defun create-problem (state)
  (let ((problem (make-problem :current-state state)))
    (setf (problem-solution problem)
          (lambda ()
            (null (state-moves-left (problem-current-state problem)))))
    problem))
```

But: Why not use a function/method directly?

```
(defmethod problem-solution ((p problem))
  (null (state-moves-left (problem-current-state p))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is that structures in Common Lisp cannot be used as classes: inside the function default value of the slot `solution` there is no way of referring to the slots of the structure itself (as you are trying to do with `(state-moves-left :current-state)`.

If you insist in using structures instead of classes, one possibility is to define the function with a parameter, and pass the structure itself when the function is called. Something like:

```
(defstruct problem
    (current-state)
    (solution (function (lambda (p) (null (state-moves-left p))))))

(let ((p0 (make-problem :current-state (make-state))))
  (funcall (problem-solution p0) p0))
```